# Does applying an OTA update remove rooted apps?

Tags: applications, htc-one-x, ota-update, root-access

I rooted my HTC One X just to get FM and other AT&T blocked apps installed in /system/app directory. Now there is an OTA update and I'm sure it will unroot the phone. My question is will the FM app stay and work after the OTA? Thanks.

Comment: This mostly just depends on how they distribute the OTA. If it formats `/system` then yes (Kindle Fire does this), if it's an incremental (patch) update then probably not.

Answer (score 1):

As eldarerathis already said in his comment, this very much depends on how the OTA is performed. First, some OTAs might even fail to execute, as rooting modified the `/system` partition and they check the CRC sum which then no longer matches (I had that with my HTC Wildfire/Buzz more than a year ago).

If they don't care about CRC, the answer still is "yes and no": Some OTAs are just "incremental" (replacing/adding single files); those wouldn't touch your root-apps, and root would be retained. However, *full* updates (and this includes most "version bumps", e.g. from Android 2.2 to 2.3 to 4.0) are completely "replacing" the `/system` partition; in this case root is gone along with all the other system apps.